# Bootstrap: Different menu type depending on page

Tags: angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have a regular text menu on one page (for example: the homepage) and a mobile ("hamburger") menu on all other pages regardless of screen size?

How might that logic work in Bootstrap and/or AngularJS?

Comment: For your first question, yes it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but your have to code for both menu.

For bootstrap normal menu bar just add the classes `hidden-xs hidden-sm` so that it will hide on mobile view port

And then for hamburger menu just add the class `hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl` This will hide the hamburger for desktop and other screen viewports

Comment: I want it to hide the mobile menu on the home page (index.html), but display the mobile menu on all other pages though. Doesn't matter what the screen size is. Currently "index.html" is being used as a template for the other pages, so they don't have a header section. I fit the content of those pages in with `<div ng-view></div>`

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to have 2 menu:
(a) class="mobile-menu"
(b)class ="desktop-menu"

You can add for home page to body, or html or any upper wrapper you have(class="home" or etc. something similar), and than hide mobile menu for index, and for other pages hide desktop menu

so you should have in css something like that

```
.home .mobile-menu{
display: none;
}
```

^this will hide mobile only for page marked as home

```
.desktop-menu{
display: none;
}
.home .desktop-menu{
display: block;
}
```